# Short story where a woman on the moon turns off the hologram trees and garden

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, moon

Does anyone recognise this story? It was in a sci-fi anthology I found in a charity shop and have since lost.

A woman lives with her husband in a town on the moon. He goes to work every day and she is left at home, bored and lonely. She looks out of the kitchen window and can only see as far as a line of holographic trees at the end of the garden. She comes to hate these trees.

Eventually she decides to go and turn the hologram off. She goes into the garden and finds the hologram projector box.

First switch is marked ‘trees’. She turns it off and the hated trees disappear.

Second switch is marked ’garden’. She turns it off and the garden disappears.

Now she sees a third switch: ‘house’. Turns it off and her home disappears. Now she is alone on the lunar surface.

She notices a final switch. It’s labelled ‘housewife’. She turns it off.

Comment: [Mariana by Fritz Leiber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265326/series-of-switches-controlling-reality-short-story).

Comment: I searched the site for [switch disappear](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+switch+disappear) and it was the second result.

Comment: Thanks! This is brilliant!

Comment: Closed as duplicate; OP accepted comment-answer via comment.